# How to find and change a line of code, then re-execute the whole code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As the title says, I need to know how to find a specific line of code. Like in a third-party script that I have loaded in through a website, for example [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js). I need to edit one line of code, and then re-execute the whole code with the edit. Is this possible?

I'm imagining something like:

```
function LoadMyJs() {
    var docHeadObj = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var dynamicScript = document.createElement("script");
    dynamicScript.type = "text/javascript";
    dynamicScript.innerHTML = anotherString;
    docHeadObj.appendChild(dynamicScript);
};

var testString = new String;
jQuery.get("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js", function (data) {
    var testString = data;
});
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = testString;
var anotherString = testString.replace(/lineOfCodeHere/g, "newCodeHere");
document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = anotherString;
```

[My JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G55Hr/)

I am not able to make this work.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Weird `jQuery.get("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js")`

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just host the script yourself, with all the required changes?

Comment: It's not specifically jQuery I want to change, but rather an annoying small script that I do not want to remove, but just change the functionality of a bit so it works better for me (locally, of course!), if this is not illegal?

Comment: @Satpal Haha, that was just for an example! But when you mention it, it looks pretty funny!

Comment: @hugomg Do you mean like using something like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to force my own response with a custom script to the request of that script? I think that would be too troublesome.
Or do you mean something else?

Comment: My initial though was just serving it from your own server. If you can send a "library modifier" script to the user, what is stopping you from also sending the library instead of telling the user to download it from a 3rd party?

Comment: @hugomg Unfortunately, the library is not mine to modify (I do not have permission nor any ownership to the server). But it would be best to just use something like [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/)/[Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) to locally edit the script per user, and avoid any interference with the server or any 3rd party files.

Comment: Sounds like greasemonkey is the way to go then. If I were you I would first try to see if I can get the desired results using a simple userscript or monkey patching. If not, another possibility is to try to block the original script and then run a modified local copy w/ greasemonkey.

Comment: @hugomg I am not familiar with the term "Monkey Patching", but if there is a way to "cancel" the requested script or overwrite it with my own local script with Greasemonkey, I would be happy to hear how! :-)

Comment: monkey patching is just running a separate script that overwrites some globally accessible variables and functions.